# Will WSO2 identity server 5.1.0 support OpenID Connect Discovery / jwks_uri

Tags: wso2-identity-server

Will the upcoming WSO2 IS 5.1.0 support OpenID Connect discovery spec? 
More particularly I am interested whether IS supports jwks_uri which is part of discovery. Many OpenID Connect clients rely on jwks_uri in order to retrieve the keys for signature validation of ID tokens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WSO2 IS 5.1.0 will not support OIDC discovery spec. Most probably it will available in IS 5.2.0